# how to convert firebase object? to map<String , dynamic> flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, typeerror

I want to conver the firebase incoming data from object? to Map<String , dynamic>. please help

```
fetchInitialNotificationData()async{
    emit(NotificationLoading());
    try{

      reference.child("User").orderByKey().onValue.listen((event) { 
       final  userNames =Map<String , dynamic>.from(event.snapshot.value);
       print(userNames);
        });

        List<String> userList = [];
        emit(NotificationContains(userList: userList));
      
      
    }
    catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Comment: Which object do you want to use as Map?

Answer (score 1):

```
querySnapshot.docs
        .map((e) => PurchaseModel.fromJson(e.data() as Map<String, dynamic>));
```

Try this //